# MySql Permission for certain Users

Tags: mysql

can you edit people's permission on PhpMyAdmin? like this guy can be a mod (Has more permissions) and this other guy cannot on the website by editing. Is it possible

Comment: Add few things like what have you tried ? and what do you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this case by pseudo code

Create  a table users to keep records of users.

```
create table user( username varchar(20), password varchar(20),isadmin int);
```

In your isadmin field allow only two values 1 (admin) or 0 (normal user)

now

`Set Session[admin]==isAdmin (0 or 1)`

Create a admin panel. Check if

```
if(Session[admin]==1)
{

delete from users where id = id_passed_from_user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't know about *mods*. For almost all web apps, there's just one MySQL "user" credential. The web app code uses that single credential for all its database work.

It's the web app using MySQL that knows about mods.

You haven't mentioned the web app you use. But, in general the answer to your question is "no."